# message:"DTS is not allowed for Package : com.example.news_app"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3, flutter

when i make update dart and flutter that is from version 29 to version 30,this message will appear for me
"DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.example.news_app".
i write this command in terminal,the result has been displayed as shown below

i want to check specified version of the Android SDK in [news_app1]/android/app/src/build.gradle match with your installed Android SDK version on my computer ??

**C:\Users\Hisham\AndroidStudioProjects\news_app1>flutter doctor -v**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 2.2.0-11.0.pre.136, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928], locale ar-IL)
    • Flutter version 2.2.0-11.0.pre.136 at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f789acae41 (20 hours ago), 2021-04-15 19:14:02 -0500
    • Engine revision 0ee8f267df
    • Dart version 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-4.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Hisham\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.4
    • Dart plugin version 202.6397.47

[√] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Hisham\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM J700H (mobile) • 5203666fb8dd53e5 • android-arm    • Android 6.0.1 (API 23)
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome           • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.128
    • Edge (web)        • edge             • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.76
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
   // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.news_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

and project structure as shown below in image:
[image: project structure]
and Android sdk as shown below in image:
[image: Android sdk]

in some cases when i make run a project, message get me android.jar does not exist
and path of Sdk\platforms\android-30 as shown below in image:
[image: Sdk\platforms\android-30]
in this case what is solution?